# Is there any utility to check whether my laptop battery is in healthy condition or not?

Tags: software-recommendation, battery

Is there any utility available on Ubuntu to check whether laptop battery is in healthy condition or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try [**Battery Status 0.1**](http://live.gnome.org/BatteryStatus)

> Battery Status is a project for GNOME, that shows information about laptop battery state. It has some additional features, so usual icon of GNOME Power Manager can be removed from Notification/Indicator Area. Battery Status doesn't rely on GNOME Power Manager directly, but counting on presence in system for some useful integration with it.

[image]
**Features:**

**Using the Battery Status applet, the user can access:**

- Battery Status dialog
- Power Statistics (provided by GNOME Power Manager)
- "Show" setting
- CPU frequency scaling (provided by gnome-applets/cpufreq-applet)
- Power Management preferences (provided by GNOME Power Manager)

Add the ppa `ppa:iaz/battery-status` to your software sources ([here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)) and install battery-status from the software center .

**You can run it as an indicator using the following command:**

`/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator`

Comment: If, like me you tried to do this too early in the morning for my brain to work you may struggle to get it to actually start running. In a terminal run /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator and it works . You can then put an insert into your main menu or start up with the above command to start it off

Comment: advice taken :) Has it disapeared?

Comment: nifty little programme..will use it myself now. been messing lots with powertop to increase my battery life which could be better

Answer (score 8):

Clicking on the battery icon on the panel and choose the battery option from the menu.

In the resulting window, highlight your battery on the left and make sure the `Details` tab is selected.  The interesting details are the `Energy when full` and `Energy (design)` values.

If the battery is new, the two values should be almost identical.  If the maximum charge is significantly less than the design charge, then it indicates that your battery is getting old.

Comment: oh wow or rather oh cripes.!!! My design was 52 but now energy when full is 46...mind you I have had this for a couple of years Still pretty good really

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your battery is bad, a good way to find out is to run the "Power Statistics" tool.

[image]

In this tool there is a Laptop Battery section. Check the "Energy (Design)" section. As you can see from mine my batter has lost a bit of capacity over time. This will let you determine if the battery is bad.

See also:

- [How to check battery status using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal)