# Ubuntu shuts down at 55% battery level

Tags: battery

For some reason Ubuntu seems to think 55% is 'critically low' and shuts down the computer at that point. In the worst case scenario, it would be a hardware related problem (didn't have this issue in the past 2 years I've used this laptop though), but is there a way for me to find that out for sure, and if it is a software issue how would I fix it?

I can provide additionnal information if it is requested.

Answer (score 3):

1. To change the percentage value for warning, type:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 30
   ```

   **Change 30 to your desired value.**
2. To change the percentage value for critical warning, type:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 20
   ```

   **Change 20 to your desired value.**
3. Finally, to change the value for when your laptop shuts down, type:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 15
   ```

   **Change 15 to your desired value.**

Comment if you are having trouble with anything.

Comment: The problem is that even when this is at, say, 3% (as in my case), the laptop may already shut down at, say, 70% (as happened to me yesterday). In other words, something is lying about the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it's a software glitch or a hardware [this applet](https://askubuntu.com/a/48836/462484) might come in handy. It'll inform you about your battery's capacity.